# Unable to install vnc server as unable to update

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, networking, apt

I have just installed Raspbian on my Raspberry Pi. Now I want to install the GUI. So for that, I tried to install VNC server by runing

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Which gave me the error:

```
temporary failure resolving 'mirrordirector.raspbian.org'
```

I tried to ping google with `ping google.com` but it gives me the error:

```
unable to get host
```

How would I go about solving this issue?

Comment: Can you ping your router?

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi.  Be sure to take the tour at https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/Tour

Comment: Can you ping the router? Anything else in your intranet?

Comment: I just tried to ping google.com. It says "ping: unknown host google.com". I tried this:                                                                                                                           pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ping 192.168.1.1       and got:-
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=0.650 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=128 time=0.607 ms

--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.541/0.607/0.650/0.044 ms